# Contour integral $\int_{D_{1}}^{}e^{iz {\cosh}u-{\nu}u} du $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, special-functions, contour-integration

How do you solve the following contour integral where the contour $D_{1}$ is the path in the picture below.
Should you close the contour on the left and right making two separate rectangular areas and than apply Cauchy´s integral theorem?

$$ I(z)=\int_{D_{1}}^{}e^{iz {\cosh}u-{\nu}u} du$$

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you apply Cauchy's theorem?  What are you "solving" for?

Comment: I want to reduce this integral into a real integral

Comment: @Ron Gordon I want to get here $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{iz {\cosh}u-{\nu}u} du$$
Thank you!